# How to add BottomNavigationBar in main page

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add `BottomNavigationBar` in main to appear inside all pages.

The problem is that main page routes to Wrapper() where authentication is made.

Is there a way to do so?

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamProvider<User>.value(
  value: AuthService().user,
  child: MaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.green,
    ),
    home: Wrapper(),
  ),
 );
 }
}
```

Here is `Home()` class and if I tried to add bod: `_page[_currentTab]` I receive error because of the `Column` widget I need to put it also

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_Home createState() => _Home();
}

class _Home extends State<Home> {
final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

int _currentTab = 0;

final _page = [
Home(),
Search(),
Account(),
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamProvider<List<Profile>>.value(
  value: DatabaseService().profiles,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton.icon(
            onPressed: () async {
              await _auth.signOut();
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: Text('logout')),
      ],
    ),
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 500, child: ProfileList()),


      ],
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _currentTab,
        onTap: (int value) {
          setState(() {
            _currentTab = value;
          });
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.search,
                size: 30.0,
              ),
              title: SizedBox.shrink()),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home,
                size: 30.0,
              ),
              title: SizedBox.shrink()),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.person,
              size: 30.0,
            ),
            title: SizedBox.shrink(),
          )
        ]),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom `Navigator` in `MaterialApp` home: [Navigator class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html)

```
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Navigator(
          initialRoute: 'Wrapper',
          onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
            WidgetBuilder builder;

            if (settings.name == 'Wrapper') {
              builder = (BuildContext _) => Wrapper();
            }

            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: builder, settings: settings);
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Current Tab:

```
    body: _currentTab == 0 ? Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 500, child: ProfileList()),


      ],
    ) : _page[_currentTab],
```

Comment: if you could give me the example with adding `body : _page[_currentTab]` and `body:Scaffold()' I would appreciate it

Comment: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/09f70bfaa6cd44d15d49bbe6c50cfbbb

Comment: Thanks man it worked as I wanted .. great job I appreciate it

Comment: Great!!~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You need to add a `Scaffold` to your page. Scaffold has a [bottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/bottomNavigationBar.html) property where you can add you bottom navbar

Comment: the problem that if I add Scaffold I can not add Wrapper() to home: property

Comment: Why not? What has Wrapper in it? You could add Scaffold as a child of Wrapper

Comment: I tried to add it inside Wrapper() but it gives me error that parameter child isn't defined

Comment: Please add your code for Wrapper so I can understand what is the issue you're having

Comment: that is what inside Wrapper `class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    print(user);

    if (user == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      return Home();
    }
  }
}`

Comment: So you want the bottonNavBar inside home or it should be visible both in Authenticate and Home?

Comment: I want it in Home

Comment: So you can do `return Scaffold(body: Home(), bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavigationBar,);`
Does it work?

Comment: No it did not work, that is why I tried to add it in main

Comment: Please add to the question you full code for `Home()`. That is where you have the problem

Comment: I need to add `body : _page[_currentTab]`  so I can switch between pages, and if I add `body: Home()` I can not add _page[_currentTab]

Answer (score 0):

Here you go for full example:

```
 // Create an Index
int _selectedIndex = 0;
static const TextStyle optionStyle = 
  TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight:FontWeight.bold);
static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
  Text(
   'Index 0: Home',
   style: optionStyle,
  ),
  Text(
   'Index 1: Business',
   style: optionStyle,
  ),
  Text(
   'Index 2: School',
   style: optionStyle,
  ),
];

void _onItemTapped(int index) {
  setState(() {
    _selectedIndex = index;
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
    ),
    body: Center(
      child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.business),
          title: Text('Business'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.school),
          title: Text('School'),
        ),
      ],
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
      onTap: _onItemTapped,
    ),
  );
}
```